# how to delete duplicate character from a string

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

The problem asks me to write a method to delete the duplicate characters from the original string and return the new string.For example, the original string is abracadabra and the result should be abrcd.

I was thinking about using StringBuilder to delete the character, but something went wrong when I tried to run the code. can anyone help me fix it.

```
public static String eliminateDuplicates(String str){
    String result = "";
    StringBuilder strings = new StringBuilder(str);
    for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++){
        for(int j = 1; j<str.length();j++){
            if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j)){
                strings.deleteCharAt(j);
            }
        }
    }
    result = strings.toString();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Mutating something while you're iterating over it is always a recipe for disaster...

Comment: Rather than deleting, think in terms of building a copy of the original string, adding characters one by one, except skipping those that are already there.  `StringBuilder` doesn't provide a very good way of looking up characters, so consider keeping track of what's in there with a `Set<Character>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, maybe your can optimize :

```
public static String eliminateDuplicates(String source) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, sLength = source.length(); i < sLength; i++) {
        char readyToAdd = source.charAt(i);
        boolean add = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < result.length(); j++) {
            if (readyToAdd == result.charAt(j)) {
                add = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (add) result.append(readyToAdd);
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static String eliminateDuplicates(String str){
    int[] uniq = str.codePoints().distinct().toArray();
    return new String(uniq, 0, uniq.length);
}
```

Comment: is this java 8?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes.

Comment: it worked. but I don't understander your code. Can you explain a bit? thank you

Comment: @HongxuLin `str.codePoints()` creates a character stream of `str`. `distinct()` deletes duplicates of them. `toArray()` makes them to an array of int.  And finally `new String()` reconstructs it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Using @P.J's idea

```
public static String eliminateDuplicates(String str) {
    HashSet<Character> hashSet = new HashSet();
    //A hashSet is a collection that only adds unique elements.

    char[] toCharArray = str.toCharArray();
    for (char c : toCharArray) {
        hashSet.add(c);
    }

    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character character : hashSet) {
        answer.append(character);
    }

    return answer.toString();
}
```

Comment: I would change `answer` to be a `StringBuilder` rather than a `String`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Done

Answer (score 0):

The code in question is iterating over input string but using the index to delete characters from the string builder object.

Every time the string builder deletes the character it will reduce in size. So, your code will fail with *IndexOutofBoundsException*. Please add the entire stack trace of the exception in the question to confirm, if that's the case.

A better approach to deleting duplicates is to create another string by iterating over the input string and then copying only the unique characters to new string. The new string can then be returned as a result.

This will also have better time complexity of `O(n*m)`compared to current code which had time complexity of `O(n*n)`

Comment: If Java Collections, Hashset is used then yes you're right it will be O(n). I was pointing to dumb comparison of current character with each unique character without using collections. Obviously the former approach is better, but latter is easier to understand and implement for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static String eliminateDuplicates(String str){
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    BitSet bs=new BitSet(256);
    char[] chars=str.toCharArray();
    char getChar=0;
    for(int i=0;i<chars.length;i++){
        getChar=chars[i];
        if(!bs.get(getChar)){
            result.append(getChar);
            bs.set(getChar);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```